# Edge-disjoint Hamiltonian cycles in a planar graph.

Tags: graph-theory, examples-counterexamples, planar-graphs, hamiltonian-path

Is it possible to have a planar graph with two edge-disjoint Hamiltonian cycles?

Comment: Look at everyone's favorite planar graphs, the Platonic solids

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. Here is an example on the octahedron. It is easy to see that this is the smallest possible example, since if $G$ has fewer than $6$ vertices, or $6$ vertices with fewer edges, there aren't enough edges for two separate Hamilton cycles.

[image]